# specify dtypes when saving pandas dataframe to a binary file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas DataFrame I want to write to a binary file, however the df contains mixed dtypes. If I used `df.values.tofile()` I cannot specify different dtypes (even when specifying `astype('f4, f4, i4, i4').tofile()` in below example). Workaround at the moment is to use `struct` but is very slow!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random(size=(10, 4)) * 10, columns=['f1', 'f2', 'i1', 'i2'])
df.i1 = df.i1.astype(int)
df.i2 = df.i2.astype(int)

with open('tmp', 'w') as ply:    

    for ix, row in df.iterrows():

        ply.write(struct.pack('<ffii', *row.values))
```

I am creating a `.ply` file which requires the data to be formatted correctly.

Comment: Can't you just use dtype=int as parameter while creating DataFrame?

Comment: The issue is when writing to a binary file using `tofile()` all fields are converted to floats and mixed dtypes can't be specified

Comment: Um.. I don't see a problem in here. If you pass all-integers DataFrame to a binary file then it may be implicitly converted to float, right? And while unpacking DF from a binary file just remember to change them to integers once again. I don't think that any precision-related issues may occur here.

Comment: I will be creating a `.ply` file which requires data to be formatted correctly, this is then read by third party software - not back into python.

Comment: The problem is you are using `. iterrows `, which will promote everything to a type that can handle all the different dtypes in your columns, in this case, float. You could have just used `itertuples` instead (or as you discovered, use .to_records`, which is the best way probably)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems to be `df.to_records(index=False).tobytes()`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random(size=(10, 4)) * 10, columns=['f1', 'f2', 'i1', 'i2'])
df.i1 = df.i1.astype(int)
df.i2 = df.i2.astype(int)

with open('test.dat', 'w') as fh:

    fh.write(df.to_records(index=False).tobytes())

arr = np.fromfile('test.dat', dtype='f8, f8, i8, i8')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df2.columns = ['f1', 'f2', 'i1', 'i2'] # strange but if columns specified above then df2 == df is False :\
print np.all(df2 == df)
```